# Separate Column Name and Text & Pivot in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a super messy .txt file with delimiter | that I want to read into python. Right now, it's structured like this:

```
Name: Name1
Location: Location1
Address: Address1
...
|
Name: Name2
Location: Location2
Address: Address2
...
|
Name: Name3
Location: Location3
Address: Address3
...
|
```

and so forth.
Each entry has 164 'columns' and the whole thing has about 2.5 million rows right now. I need to separate these entries by the delimiter | in a vertical way I guess?, and then figure out a way to assign the column name as column name *once* and subsume all entries below that.

What I've written so far:

```
import pandas as pd

extract = pd.read_csv(r'myfile',
            encoding='utf8', sep='\|', index_col=False, names=['A'])

extract = extract.dropna()

to_drop = ["way too many strings aka columns I don't need because I couldn't figure out how to automate this"]

extract = extract[~extract['A'].str.contains('|'.join(to_drop))]

print(extract)
```

This prints my column full of crap, but I can't figure out how to do the important 'separate stuff into columns' bit.

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: kindly include ur expected output

Answer (score 0):

read in the data, using `;` or some other delimiter not present in the data, and `squeeze` into a series. From hereon, you can split the column and drop null rows:

NB: I used `read_clipboard`, replace ith with `read_csv`, since you have the actual file:

```
 df = (pd.read_clipboard(sep=";", squeeze=True)
       .str.split(":",expand=True)
       .dropna(how='any')
       )

df

         0       1
0   Location    Location1
1   Address     Address1
4   Name        Name2
5   Location    Location2
6   Address     Address2
9   Name        Name3
10  Location    Location3
11  Address     Address3
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is fun :)

You can use the `lineterminator` and `sep` arguments to treat newlines as columns and pipes as row delimiters. This requires the `c` engine, so you're going to be missing a couple features, but what you get is a good starting point:

```
In [5]: df = pd.read_csv(
   ...:     fp,
   ...:     lineterminator='|',
   ...:     sep='\n',
   ...:     engine='c',
   ...:     header=None,
   ...:     names=['Name', 'Location', 'Address', 'offset'],
   ...: )

In [6]: df
          Name             Location              Address             offset
0  Name: Name1  Location: Location1    Address: Address1                NaN
1          NaN          Name: Name2  Location: Location2  Address: Address2
2          NaN          Name: Name3  Location: Location3  Address: Address3
```

This is messy but it's a start... you could modify your source data by replacing `|\n` with `|`, but you can also just shift rows 1+ with:

```py
In [7]: df.iloc[1:, :-1] = df.iloc[1:, 1:].values
In [8]: df = df.iloc[:, :-1]
In [9]: df
          Name             Location            Address
0  Name: Name1  Location: Location1  Address: Address1
1  Name: Name2  Location: Location2  Address: Address2
2  Name: Name3  Location: Location3  Address: Address3
```

Now you can clean the columns with string operations, e.g.:

```py
In [10]: for col in df.columns:
    ...:     df[col] = df[col].str.extract(rf'{col}: (.*)', expand=False)
    ...:
In [11]: df
    Name   Location   Address
0  Name1  Location1  Address1
1  Name2  Location2  Address2
2  Name3  Location3  Address3
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ahh yeah if you don't know the order or full set of columns in the data then @sammywemmy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62181886/3888719) is probably better.